# JLists with Arraylists?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, listener, jlist

I'm working on a project that requires GUI, but I have no experience with GUI, so everything I have been doing is guesswork in a sense.
I have a created an arraylist of objects that I have put into a JList, and now I am trying to change the text in a label based on what the user chooses. I get an error that says **"Cannot refer to a non-final variable library inside an inner class defined in a different method"**

The arraylist I am using is populated with objects that I can call strings from

How  do I get this to work?

```
JList list = new JList(bookNames.toArray());

list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        typeLabel.setText(library.get(list.getSelectedIndex()).getType());
    }
});
```

Comment: If it has to be final, then how do I make my arraylist populate it correctly?

Comment: the contents of your list can still change, even if it is declared "final" - you just cannot assign another value to the "list" variable

Comment: "If it has to be final, then how do I make my arraylist populate it correctly?" We could better answer this question if you posted all of the code involved in this project.

Comment: THANKS GUYS
I got it down! Now just to copypasta my code a couple times and that's a semicomplete project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the typeLabel variable inside your new ListSelectionListener(){...}.

```
JList list = new JList(bookNames.toArray());

list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        // you cannot access typeLabel here
        typeLabel.setText(library.get(list.getSelectedIndex()).getType());
    }
});
```

A Quick fix would be to declare the typeLabel as final.
This means that you cannot reassign another value to typeLabel but that's probably fine.

```
final typeLabel = whatever; // add the final modifier

final JList list = new JList(bookNames.toArray());

list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        typeLabel.setText(library.get(list.getSelectedIndex()).getType());
    }
});
```

edit:
Also, list must be declared final.

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `JList list` has to be `final`.

```
final JList list = new JList(...)
```

The `final` keyword in Java has several meanings. When used with a variable or a field this means that it always references the same object, i.e. the pointer is constant. It does not mean that the object itself is unchangeable (or immutable).

Immutability of objects is achieved in a different way - don't give us any `public` methods that change the contents of an object. For example `String`s and `Date`s are always immutable
regardless of the `final` keyword.

Another example of `final`: When used in front of a class it means that a class cannot be subclassed.

Comment: Unfortunately `java.util.Date` is mutable, see `setTime(long)` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setTime%28long%29